# AngularJS and elasticsearch server with two nodes

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch

I have been trying for some days to run an elasticsearch server with two nodes.
I have got an AngularJS application (within Node.js) with two views/js-files and 
within each js-file I want to do a separate search via elasticsearch.

Till now, I am running two different elasticsearch servers on different localhost ports. Based on this setup at least the two different views work (i.e. correct results are shown). 
I have tried to create two nodes at one server based on the information at the elasticsearch page. But then I do not know how to approach the two nodes within my views.

Here is my source code to create the two servers:

```
"use strict";

(function () {
    var users=angular.module('myApp.users',['elasticsearch','chart.js'])

    users.controller('usersCtrl', function ($scope,elasticClient) {
        console.log("init users module");
    });
    users.factory('elasticClient', ['esFactory', function(esFactory) {  
        return esFactory({
            hosts: [
                'localhost:9200'                        
            ],
            sniffOnStart: true,
            sniffInterval: 300000 
        });
    }]);                

    users.factory('elasticClient1', ['esFactory', function(esFactory) { 
        return esFactory({
            hosts: [
                'localhost:9201'                        
            ],
            sniffOnStart: true,
            sniffInterval: 300000 
        });
    }]);                
}) ();
```

Then the JS code of my two views:
View1:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute', 'myApp.users'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
            templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
            controller: 'View1Ctrl',
            controllerAs: 'View1'
        });
    }])
    .controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope','elasticClient', function($scope, elasticClient) {   
        elasticClient.search({     
            // Query.          
        }).then(function (resp) {
            // Do SOmething with results.               
        });
    }]);
```

View2:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.view2', ['ngRoute', 'myApp.users'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/view2', {
            templateUrl: 'view2/view2.html',
            controller: 'View2Ctrl',
            controllerAs: 'View2'
        });
    }])
    .controller('View2Ctrl', ['$scope','elasticClient1', function($scope, elasticClient1) {
        elasticClient1.search({}).then(function (resp1) {});
    }]);
```

It would be great if somebody could help!

Cheers,
Andi

Comment: Why do you want to nodes on one server if you have two views? If you have just one server, one elasticsearch node is more logical.

Comment: I would like to understand the general principle how to do the setup in angularjs with more nodes. I would then have more views..

Answer (score 0):

View 1 and View 2 JavaScript both have an extra `}` that is causing `}`, `]`, and `)` to not match up.  Both directly following each views' `elasticClient.search({`.

Comment: It is now corrected as intended. The missing brackets usually worked but copying them deleted them..sorry..